# Jenkins job failed to perform log rotation message

Tags: jenkins

we are using **Jenkins 2.235.1** version running on CentOS 7 server, I have job to build nodejs project. when I run the job `jenknis.log` file giving this message.

How to fix this error?

```
2020-07-15 13:28:24.141+0000 [id=121]   INFO    h.p.t.l.JenkinsRunListener#onCompleted: onCompleted: 1000-Infrastructure/nodejsdev #51
2020-07-15 13:28:24.210+0000 [id=43]    WARNING o.j.p.workflow.job.WorkflowRun#lambda$finish$2: failed to perform log rotation after 1000-Infrastructure/nodejsdev #51
Also:   java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /data/jenkins/jobs/1000-Infrastructure/jobs/nodejsdev/builds/1 -> /data/jenkins/jobs/1000-Infrastructure/jobs/nodejsdev/builds/.1
                at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
                at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
                at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:396)
                at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:262)
                at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1395)
                at hudson.model.Run.delete(Run.java:1645)
                at hudson.tasks.LogRotator.perform(LogRotator.java:166)
jenkins.util.io.CompositeIOException: Failed to rotate logs for [1000-Infrastructure/nodejsdev #1]
        at hudson.tasks.LogRotator.perform(LogRotator.java:223)
        at hudson.model.Job.logRotate(Job.java:469)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.lambda$finish$2(WorkflowRun.java:620)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingScheduledExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingScheduledExecutorService.java:58)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-07-15 13:29:58.735+0000 [id=47]    INFO    o.j.p.P.u.DropCachePeriodicWork#doRun: begin schedule clean...
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a bug already open for this on Jenkins Jira

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-61687

Hope they push the fix out soon.